# Efficient way to write excel from C#

Tags: c#, performance, excel

I'm trying to generate excel using c# following is the code snippet for it

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
.
.
.
foreach (string[] rowContents in lstOutputFileContent)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rowContents.Length; i++)
    {
        sheet.Cells[currRow, i + 1] = rowContents[i];
    }
}
```

but the problem is when lstOutputFileContent contains say more than 50K line then its taking too long to write (4-5 mins). Is there a better/faster way to write excel in this scenario i.e. I've list of array of string and I want to write this to excel.

I tried using OleDb but in case where first few lines contain less cells then when I try to insert row with extra cell it was giving error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question was dealt with in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840270/fastest-way-to-interface-between-live-unsaved-excel-data-and-c-sharp-objects

Comment: You are writing 50k rows to a file. It ain't going to ever be that fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2007 or higher, the best option is [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124)

You can also modify the current method.  Instead of writing each value individually, create a two-dimensional array to hold all the values.  Then get a range of the same size and set the value for the range to be the two-dimensional array.  That way you only suffer the cost of one marshalled COM call instead of the many, many you were dealing with.

Comment: Indeed, using 2-dimentional array with Range is the fastest solution.

Comment: But when you insert using range then numbers are also inserted as string in excel, which is changing the expected behaviour of output file

Comment: aashutoshsingh: That's not quite true.  If you make an array of *object*, then put strings or numbers into it, the spreadsheet will type the cell to match the object's type.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a row at a time instead of a cell at a time using the code in my answer at [Excel C# inputting into specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405495/excel-c-sharp-inputting-into-specific-cell/7405643#7405643)

I got to that when I encountered performance problems I believe similar to yours.

Comment: +1, This will reduce the number of round trips to Excel from (RowCount * RowSize) to (RowCount), a significant improvement.  But if RowCount > 50K, you still have a lot of round trips.  You can go further and insert a 2-dimensional array into a Range on one call.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel 2002 (?) or higher, you may simply serve your spreadsheet content in HTML format, using a simple table: please see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excelxmlspreadsheet.aspx) for a simple example. This will be the **fastest** option.