# How to append a data to existing excel file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to append a data to a existing excel file using c#.I Tried it using below codes,but it is giving wrong column value after opening of the excel file(if my excel file contains 4 columns,but here it is returning column count as 1 only).

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);   //@"H:\TestFile.xlsx"
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(sheetNum);

            rng = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            int colCount = rng.Columns.Count;
            int rowCount = rng.Rows.Count;
            rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, colCount];
            Excel.Range newColumn = rng.EntireColumn;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, colCount + 3] = "Udupi";

            xlWorkBook.Save();
            xlWorkBook.Close(misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
```

How can i append a data to excel file?Is there any other methods are  available to achieve this one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources for learning c# Excel interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175763/resources-for-learning-c-sharp-excel-interop)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Epplus library for creating and editing Excel spreadsheets and workbooks in C#? I have worked on it before some weeks ago. It is super. I recommend to use it.