# XValue propery in excel interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I want to change the Xvalues in excel chart using Interop.
Following is what I am using. But it is not recognising Range.

Can anybody help me solve this?

```
    chartPage.SetSourceData Range("A2:A4"), xlColumns
    chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2:B4")
```

It is not accepting Range, everywhere I am finding same answer.

Comment: That looks like VBA code and not C#. The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175763/resources-for-learning-c-sharp-excel-interop may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the active worksheet and use range on it. Something like this:

```
_Worksheet ws = this.ActiveSheet
chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("B2:B4")
```