# How to fetch a excel file from a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a excel file in a folder. but **i dont know to fetch that file from the folder**.

but I'm checking whether the file exists.

here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Sample.xlsx");
     bool fileexists = File.Exists(filePath); //Here fileexists = true    
}
```

I need to save that excel file in sql database.

I need to save the fileName(varchar(256)),Data(varbinary(max)),Path(varchar(256)) of that excel file into sql database.

please help me out

Comment: all you have to do is to convert your file in stream and then byte array and save it in db using any standard `ADO.NET` db class, did you face any problem doing so? did you even try it?

Comment: Convert the file into byte[] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-byte-array-in-c) and get the name and the path and save them. Personally i would suggest to save only the path and name if the is possibility to save a lot of files.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175763/resources-for-learning-c-sharp-excel-interop#176130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler than you think, it should be something like:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) {   
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    const string query = "INSERT INTO Files (FileName, Data, Path) VALUES (@FileName, @Data, @Path)";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", data);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", filePath);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get and read an xlsx file .

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("path")))
{
             string filename = Path.GetFileName("path");// to get filename
 string conStr = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);// get extension
        if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx")
        {
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 1997-2003
                    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source='" + mappingPath + "';" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 2007
                    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source='" + mappingPath + "';" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr.ToString());
            OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            connExcel.Open();

            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            ViewState["SheetName"] = SheetName;
            //Selecting Values from the first sheet
            //Sheet name must be as Sheet1
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]", conStr.ToString()); // to fetch data from excel 
            da.Fill(dtExcel);

}
```

Comment: Hmm? I think you've misread the question - "how to save a file as byte array to SQL's varbinary filed". Your answer is to totally different "how to read data from Excel file".